# Public key authentication as zero-knowledge proof?

Tags: public-key, srp

I've been reading up a bit on zero-knowledge proofs and how they are applied to authentication, specifically the PAKE protocol and the SRP and OPAQUE implementations. From my (limited) understanding this seems similar to Public Key authentication (for example as used as a means of authentication in SSH) or Personal Access Tokens (as used in most Git platforms like Gitlab, Github, Bitbucket or Azure). Could one therefore state that Public Key authentication is an example of zero-knowledge proofs? Or am I missing something here? Does the public key convey some knowledge of the private key?

Comment: I googled your question title and this was the first hit: https://doubleoctopus.com/security-wiki/protocol/zero-knowledge-proof/#:~:text=One%20example%20for%20zero%2Dknowledge,the%20prover%20has%20the%20key.

Comment: Yes, they state "One example for zero-knowledge authentication is when a prover has an asymmetric key-pair (e.g. RSA, EC)", though I've read (or understood) otherwise in other places. Eg [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35177/is-using-digital-signatures-to-prove-identity-a-zero-knowledge-proof) (not the same question, but similar) there are comments regarding "I want to prove to YOU (...), but I don't want you to be able to convince anyone else that you interacted with (me)"

Answer (score 1):

*Could one therefore state that Public Key authentication is an example of zero-knowledge proofs?*
Yes and No, it is related to but still distinct from a zero-knowledge proof.
I think the discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/75quwb/how_is_a_zeroknowledge_proof_different_than_rsa/ will answer your question.

In `public key authentication`, the scheme is based on public key cryptography, using cryptosystems where encryption and decryption are done using separate keys, and it is not feasible to derive the decryption key from the encryption key. Each user creates a public/private key pair for authentication purposes. The server knows the public key, and only the user knows the private key.

In cryptography, a `zero-knowledge proof` or zero-knowledge protocol is a method by which one party (the prover) can prove to another party (the verifier) that a given statement is true while the prover avoids conveying any additional information apart from the fact that the statement is indeed true.
Zero-knowledge authentication is when a prover convinces a verifier that she is in possession of an identifying secret, without revealing the secret itself.

An example of that could be using an asymmetric private-public key pair, with the private key acting as the verifier of the information requested. The verifier sends a challenge or request using the public key, and the prover responds using the private key to confirm the information. The public-private key "handshake" convinces the verifier that the prover's key meets the criteria, resulting in successful authentication.
Some refer to this as ZKKSP: https://coingeek.com/zero-knowledge-key-statement-proof/

See more here:

- https://github.com/matter-labs/awesome-zero-knowledge-proofs
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89875/are-zero-knowledge-proofs-alternative-private-key-encryption
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/92178/zero-knowledge-rsa-public-key
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64059/are-ssh-key-pairs-an-example-of-a-zero-knowledge-proof
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10595/when-would-one-prefer-a-proof-of-knowledge-instead-of-a-zero-knowledge-proof?rq=1
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25338/why-arent-zero-knowledge-proofs-used-in-practice-for-authentication?rq=1

Comment: To me the Reddit post doesn't answer very much - they seem to have gone off on a bit of a tangent (I understand the poster probably was asking a similar question to mine, but the answers seem to compare PK auth with ZKP in general, not ZKP auth in particular). However _your_ answer is much more helpful. PK auth would basically be a ZKKSP protocol, no? I find it strange it is never really mentioned as such, considering the interest in ZKP.

Comment: And, if I understand correctly, even if PK auth is zero-knowledge, protocols like SRP/OPAQUE are interesting from a usability point of view (especially on the web) as the user doesn't need to save a private key anywhere or keep it safe.